# How to tell YouTube I have permission to use copyrighted music?

Tags: youtube, permissions, copyright

This is an unusual situation for me, but I've been asked to produce a video which will be posted on YouTube — and in doing so, I may have permission to use a well-known copyrighted song in that content.

How do I include or assign that copyright permission in my video so that YouTube's automatic Content ID system does not demonetize or block it?

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is a way to do this upon uploading the video.

I believe the only way you can provide evidence that you are not infringing upon anyone's copyright is once they claim you are infringing upon someone's copyright. Then you will be able to reply to their request for proof of permission with whatever you'd like that you believe will help your case.

If you were uploading a lot of content fairly consistently, you may be able to apply for a [content ID](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2797370?vid=0-1373262315226-1497701804576) which would make this process easier.